# Plot with gridline on top of XYDifferenceRenderer

Tags: java, jfreechart, timeserieschart

I'm making (time series) moutain chart using JFreeChart. So, i made 2 timeseries - the data one and the one with all range values are zero.

```
  TimeSeriesCollection dataset2 = new TimeSeriesCollection();
  dataset2.addSeries(close); //my data series/
  dataset2.addSeries(zeroseries); /zero series/
```

Then, i used XYDifferenceRenderer to fill the gap between 2 series with my desired color.

Code to create the chart and set renderer :

```
  final JFreeChart chart = garch_differencechart(url);//my method to create the chart//
  final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
  final XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
  chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
  plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
  XYDifferenceRenderer renderer = new XYDifferenceRenderer();
  renderer.setPositivePaint(new Color(202, 225, 255));
  renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, new Color(72, 118, 255));
  renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(1.2f));
  plot.setRenderer(renderer);
```

Code to set GridLines visible :

```
 plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(true);
 plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(new Color(234,234,234));
 plot.setDomainGridlineStroke(new BasicStroke(0.5f));


 plot.setRangeGridlinesVisible(true);
 plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(new Color(234,234,234));
 plot.setRangeGridlineStroke(new BasicStroke(0.5f));
```

[image]However, the renderer covered the plot's gridline (it seems that the gridline was painted before the XYDifferenceRenderer).

How could I get the plot with gridline on top of XYDifferenceRenderer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gridlines show though in the [demos](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) and [API](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYDifferenceRenderer.html). An [sscce](http://sscce.org/) would be dispositive, but I suspect your grid and fill paints just need more contrast.

Comment: Yes, in HSB space, those colors are quite close, with both having very low saturation. To get the gridlines on top, you'd have to change the rendering order specified in [`draw()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html#draw%28java.awt.Graphics2D,%20java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D,%20java.awt.geom.Point2D,%20org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotState,%20org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotRenderingInfo%29).

Comment: @trashgold : So, I must subclass XYPlot to override draw() method? But  i can't find any method in JFreeChart class to set my plot, something like : chart.setPlot(//my subclass//)?

Comment: I'd just change the contrast, but the source of the `ChartFactory` you're using shows how to specify the plot.

Comment: @trashgold   :  sorry, but i couldn't find the way to do that in ChartFactory, could you give me more hint?

Comment: See [`ChartFactory.createXYAreaChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.1590).